# gensim Getting Started Error: No such file or directory: 'text8'

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, gensim, word2vec

I am learning about word2vec and GloVe model in python so I am going through this available [here](http://textminingonline.com/getting-started-with-word2vec-and-glove-in-python).

After I compiled these code step by step in Idle3:

```
>>>from gensim.models import word2vec
>>>import logging
>>>logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
>>>sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus('text8')
>>>model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=200)
```

I am getting this error :

```
2017-01-13 11:15:41,471 : INFO : collecting all words and their counts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=200)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 469, in __init__
    self.build_vocab(sentences, trim_rule=trim_rule)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 533, in build_vocab
    self.scan_vocab(sentences, progress_per=progress_per, trim_rule=trim_rule)  # initial survey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 545, in scan_vocab
    for sentence_no, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1536, in __iter__
    with utils.smart_open(self.fname) as fin:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/smart_open-1.3.5-py3.5.egg/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 127, in smart_open
    return file_smart_open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/smart_open-1.3.5-py3.5.egg/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 558, in file_smart_open
    return open(fname, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text8'
```

How do I rectify this ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're missing the file used here. Specifically, it is trying to open `text8` and can't find it (hence the `FileNotFoundError`).

You could download the file itself from [here](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip) as is stated [in the documentation for `Text8Corpus`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Text8Corpus):

```
Docstring:      
Iterate over sentences from the "text8" corpus, unzipped from http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip .
```

and make it available. *Extract it* and then supply it as an argument to `Text8Corpus`:

```
sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus('/path/to/text8')
```

Comment: after i use svn checkout http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ i get this ... svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://word2vec.googlecode.com/svn/trunk' .... 
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk' path not found ... I typed that in my terminal

Comment: @Clueless_programmer just grab the zip, extract it and supply it as a path to `Text8Corpus`, I've changed my answer to state this.